# Implementing JSR-303 annotations into a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bean-validation

I'm working with Spring (and really Java on this level) for the first time. I have a basic Spring project that I've implemented JDBC authentication into and now I'm trying to use JSR-303 annotations to validate the input boxes on a page.

Comment: What was the "Error while committing the transaction" ?

Comment: The root cause is burried in the stack trace chain.

Comment: Here's the full error: http://pastebin.com/8mgGixc8

Comment: The root cause is below

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [springapp.domain.Product] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 1 and 255', propertyPath=description, rootBeanClass=class springapp.domain.Product, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
]

Comment: This is expected as you have not specified a value for the text field. But you need to check why your code is trying to persist the product instead of transferring to the UI screen to correct this validation error.

Comment: Thanks Pangea. Any reason you can think it would do this? What steps do I need to take to ensure that it does transfer? I have the same problem if I try to specify that the price value be non-negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed so as not to compromise the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If field is nullable simply remove the min flag ([default value is 0](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/validation/constraints/Size.html)).

Comment: Well, the field is supposed to be between 1 and 255 characters so I don't want it to be nullable, but I want it to catch that it should be in that range and give an error message.